# C# - Charting - Adding a Range to a Series

Tags: c#, charts, series, addrange

Using Microsoft's Charting control, is it possible to add a range of points at once *without* having to iterate through the List I want to add? I have a List and I need to add the entire list as the Y-values of my Series in the Charting control and simply doing this with a 'foreach' statement and

```
chart1.Series["Data"].Points
```

Seemed like it'd be more inefficient than is necessary.  I've been trying to find an answer to this on Google, but honestly I've not had much luck finding 'good' Charting examples (besides those provided by Microsoft themselves).

Thanks for reading!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you have to stick to the current iterating way, because the data types are incompatible.

PS: This is not relevant to your question, but I can't help mentioning **ZedGraph**, an powerful yet open-source charting library for C#.